# JavaFx Current position ImageView in transition

Tags: javafx, imageview, transition

Why doesn´t worked ? Do you have some idea ? I need resolve this problem i need actual position x and position y for my sprite animation.

```
Image iv1 = new Image("Images/Asteroid.png", 60, 50, false, false);
ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(iv1);
iv2.setX(100);
iv2.setY(200);

Path p = new Path();
p.getElements().add(new MoveTo(100, 200));
p.getElements().add(new LineTo(100, 400));
PathTransition pt = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(4000), p);
pt.setNode(iv2);
root.getChildren().add(iv2);   
DoubleProperty xValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
xValue.bind(iv2.xProperty());
xValue.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
        System.out.println("Current x : "+(double)t1);
    }
});
pt.play();
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PathTransition`, as also stated in its javadoc, changes the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the attached node, instead of X and Y properties. Additionally you are drawing a path vertically, so the value expected to be changed is translateY, thus you need bind to this value as follows:

```
xValue.bind(iv2.translateYProperty());
```

Comment: And why the translateX and translateY is bad position on my scene ? I start on coordinate x = 100 y = 200 in real my real coordinate y = -24.8 ... why ? I need real coordinates when is my ImageView is